# Error while request processing in mule application in tomcat 7 server

Tags: mule, mule-esb, mule-cluster

While request processing mule application  giving following exception:-
javax.servlet.ServletException: Property mule.context not set on ServletContext.
the flow  snippet is like below :-

```
    <logger message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message" me
    </dw:transform-message>
    <logger message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: Advanes Thanks..

Comment: The description is incomplete. Please attach the full error and flow. Which version of Mule are you using? Are you using an embedded library in a WAR application?